# Price not changing showing Static

Tags: php, wordpress, hook-woocommerce

I tried to change the price a single way, like WAS, NOW

it's working, But on the single product page, it's not working showing all variation prices line by line and when I change the variation price does not change(showing static).
snapshot here-  https://prnt.sc/Tdg19atUacwq
code here below

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'revent_custom_variable_product_price_customs' );
function revent_custom_variable_product_price_customs() { 
    global $product;
    $id = $product->get_id();
    echo '<p class="price">';
    if( $product->is_type( 'variable' )){
    // Regular Price 
        
    $v_prices = array($product->get_variation_regular_price( 'min', true ),$product->get_variation_regular_price( 'max', true ) ); 
    sort( $v_prices ); 
    $v_price =  sprintf(__(' %1$s', 'woocommerce'),   wc_price( $v_prices[1] ) ) ;
    $v_saleprice = $v_prices[0]===$v_prices[1] ? sprintf(__('<span class="revent_custom_sale_price"> %1$s   </span>','woocommerce')  , wc_price( $v_prices[0] ) ) : wc_price( $v_prices[0] ); 
    
    if ($product->is_on_sale()  ) { 
      $v_price = ' <del><span class="revent_custom_regular_price">Was: ' .$v_price.'</span>' . $product->get_price_suffix() . '</del> <ins><span class="revent_custom_sale_price">Now: '.$v_saleprice.'</span>'.$product->get_price_suffix() . '</ins></p>'; 
    }else{
         $v_price =  sprintf(__('<span class="revent_custom_regular_price">Now: %1$s</span></p>', 'woocommerce'),   wc_price( $v_prices[0] ) ) ;
    }
        echo $v_price;

    }else{
        $regular_price = $product->get_regular_price();
        $sale_price = $product->get_sale_price();
    
    // Regular Price 
    if ($product->is_on_sale()  ) { 
      $v_price = ' <del><span class="revent_custom_regular_price"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">Was: ' .$regular_price.'<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">د.إ</span></span></span> </del> <ins><span class="revent_custom_sale_price">Now: '.$sale_price.'</span><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">د.إ</span></ins></p>'; 
    }else{
        $v_price= sprintf(__('<span class="revent_custom_regular_price">Now: %1$s</span></p>','woocommerce'), wc_price($regular_price) );
    }
    echo $v_price;
    }
    
}
```

Please help me to fix this.

Answer (score 2):

As per my understanding you are using sales option in woo commerce, for that you need to use

```
$product->get_variation_sale_price( 'max', true )
```

It will get the sale price and you can display it as you want.

Comment: tried also not working

Comment: Change the old one to this and add price in the sales field it will work, $v_prices = array($product->get_variation_regular_price( 'min', true ),$product->get_variation_sale_price( 'max', true ) );

Comment: Yes, i tried not working, not sure what all variation prices are showing the same line and also the top of the product image. - https://prnt.sc/Tdg19atUacwq

Comment: i'm using theme rehub,and plugin dokan also for variations swatches.

Comment: I have no such setup otherwise would try and debug it